# How would I skip the specific time slot in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I am creating a reservation system for the cars with instructors and its basically working correctly. I want to implement the rule where I can say want to block some additional sessions.

For example the instructor just finish session from 6:00Am to 8AM. the next available slot should be 8AM if they decide back to back scheduling and 8:15AM (if they want a break). The other sessions withing 105 minutes  span should be hidden so the next available session will at either 10AM

```
<cfloop index="ii" from="#startHour#" to="#endHour#">
<cfloop index="jj" from="0" to="#60-locbtwMinute#" step="#locbtwMinute#">
    <cfset showtime="y">
    <cfset time = createtime(ii, jj, 0)>

        <cfloop query="qAssignedSessions">

            <cfset preSessionStart = dateadd("n",-locBtwSpan-buffertime,sessionstart)>
            <cfset postSessionend = dateadd("n",bufferTime,sessionend)>

            <cfif (hour(time) gt hour(preSessionStart) or (hour(time) eq hour(preSessionStart) and minute(time) gt minute(preSessionStart)))
                                        and (hour(time) lt hour(postSessionend) or (hour(time) eq hour(postSessionend) and minute(time) lt minute(postSessionend)))>
                                    <cfset showtime="n">
                                </cfif>
                            </cfloop>

                            <cfif ((datecompare(arguments.startDt,latestSessionDate) eq 1 and ((hour(time) eq 20 and minute(time) eq 00) or hour(time) lt 20))
                                    or (datecompare(arguments.startDt,latestSessionDate) eq 0 and ((hour(time) eq 20 and minute(time) eq 00) or (hour(time) lt 20 and hour(time) gt hour(now()))))
                                        )
                                    and showtime eq "y">
                                <option value="<cfoutput>#timeformat(time, 'HH:mm')#</cfoutput>"><cfoutput>#timeformat(time, "hh:mm tt")#</cfoutput></option>
                            </cfif>
                        </cfloop>
                    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Sounds like a database job to me.

Comment: I have query qAssignedSessions that work out assigned sessions and based on that I am building my logic

Comment: This is not a debate.  You asked a question and I made a comment that I would use a different approach.

Comment: It would be useful if you added what the intended output should be. It looks like you are trying to create a pull-down menu with a bunch of times, but I am not sure the format. I am seeing 3 nested loops, and it seems like a bit much.

Comment: The Format is simple 6:00AM;6:15AM;6:30 basically the increment 15 minutes

Comment: And What I Need is this if for example from 6AM to 8 AM the session is reserved then show 8AM; 8:15AM, and the next will be 10:00am and so on with a 15 minutes increment

Comment: Please advise. I really stock making my head around the issue

Comment: I would recommend Create a table via a tabled valued SQL function then do a join to exclude unwanted time slots. Then run a simple `<cfoutput>` to generate the pulldown menu.

Comment: Help us to help you.  Please post a [*self-contained*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. There are too many unknowns in the code above for anyone to even run it: not without a lot of extra set up and assumptions. Keep in mind most people do not have a lot of time to spend.  So the more time it takes them to set up and run your code, the less likely you are to get an answer. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I figure out I just create  2 array one for time slots that are available and second for the one that are already taken and eliminate the one I do not need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out I just create 2 array one for time slots that are available and second for the one that are already taken and eliminate the one I do not need